# Is it possible to install Docker on Raspberry Pi 2 Model B?

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi2

I tried to install Docker on Raspberry Pi 2 Model B on Debian Jessie 8.0 without success.  My notes are posted at: https://github.com/mccshark/DockerInstall-RaspberryPi2Mb1.

I believe the answer to my question is no. If correct, I'll will purchase the model 3.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, I think that should be possible; check out the Hypriot Blog; http://blog.hypriot.com/getting-started-with-docker-on-your-arm-device/. They have a nice tutorial on getting it running